# Is there an upper bound for $2^x \bmod P$ in range again?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, modules, upper-lower-bounds, discrete-logarithms

Is there an upper bound for $x \in \mathbb{N}_+$ in
$$ v \cdot 2^x \equiv m \mod P $$ 
to get a remainder $m$ with
$$N\le m <2N$$
given a random initial value $v$ with:
$$N\le v <2N$$

$P$ is a safe prime (with $p=2q+1$, and $q$ prime as well)
$N\ll P$

---

**Lower bound of $x$:**

To get a value in range $[N,2N)$ again the minimal exponent $x$ should be at least $$l=\log_2 \left( \frac{P-2 \cdot N}{2\cdot N}\right)$$
(rounded to higher number)

---

**Question:**
Is there also an upper bound $u$ to shrink the number of possible solutions? (minimize $z=u-l$)

A trivial upper bound would be $u=p-1$. With this it would be value $v$ again. For some primes $P$ the upper bound can be $u=(p-1)/2$.
Is there a general smaller upper bound $u$?
If not, can a lower $u$ be constructed if $P$ (, $N$ (, $v$)) is known?

Comment: Sometimes the notation $a\bmod b$ is used to denote the remainder on division of $a$ by $b,$ and then the statement $a\bmod b = c$ can be parsed as $(a\bmod b)=c.$ But sometimes (the older usage, dating back to the publication of Gauss's _Disquisitiones Arithmeticae_ in 1801) the notation $a\equiv b\mod c$ means $a$ and $b$ both leave the same remainder on division by $c,$ and that needs to be parsed as $(a\equiv b) \mod c.$ But your notation $a\bmod b\equiv c$ fits neither usage, and I edited it. $\qquad$